# Spark shell - How can I retrieve rows from my dataset based on a time period or in between 2 given dates or two years

Tags: scala, shell, apache-spark

I recently started with spark. I am practicing on spark shell.

I've a dataset "movies.dat" and is in the following format:

MovieID,Title,Genres

Sample Record :-

```
2,Jumanji (1995),Adventure|Children|Fantasy
```

I want to generate the list of “Horror” movies released in between 1985 to 1995.

Here is my approach.

```
scala> val movies_data = sc.textFile("file:///home/cloudera/cs/movies.dat")

scala> val tags=movies_data.map(line=>line.split(","))

scala> tags.take(5)
res3: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(1, Toy Story (1995), Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy), Array(2, Jumanji (1995), Adventure|Children|Fantasy), Array(3, Grumpier Old Men (1995), Comedy|Romance), Array(4, Waiting to Exhale (1995), Comedy|Drama|Romance), Array(5, Father of the Bride Part II (1995), Comedy))

scala> val horrorMovies = tags.filter(genre=>genre.contains("Horror"))

scala> horrorMovies.take(5)
res4: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(177, Lord of Illusions (1995), Horror), Array(220, Castle Freak (1995), Horror), Array(841, Eyes Without a Face (Les Yeux sans visage) (1959), Horror), Array(1105, Children of the Corn IV: The Gathering (1996), Horror), Array(1322, Amityville 1992: It's About Time (1992), Horror))
```

I want to retrieve the data using Spark Shell only. I am able to retrieve all the movies of the "Horror" genres. 
Now, is there any way to filter out of those movies and get only the ones that have the release year in between 1985 and 1995?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write logics to extract year from the second element of the splitted line (Array) and compare with the range you have as below

```
scala> val movies_data = sc.textFile("file:///home/cloudera/cs/movies.dat")
movies_data: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = file:///home/cloudera/cs/movies.dat MapPartitionsRDD[5] at textFile at <console>:25

scala> val tags=movies_data.map(line=>line.split(","))
tags: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] = MapPartitionsRDD[6] at map at <console>:27

scala> val horrorMovies = tags.filter(genre => {
     | val date = genre(1).substring(genre(1).lastIndexOf("(")+1, genre(1).lastIndexOf(")")).toInt
     | date >= 1985 && date <= 1995 && genre(2).contains("Horror")
     | })
horrorMovies: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] = MapPartitionsRDD[7] at filter at <console>:29

scala> horrorMovies.take(3)
res1: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(177, " Lord of Illusions (1995)", " Horror"), Array(220, " Castle Freak (1995)", " Horror"), Array(1322, " Amityville 1992: It's About Time (1992)", " Horror"))
```

I hope the answer is helpful

**Edited**

You can do the above logic with `regex` too

```
scala> val horrorMovies = tags.filter(genre => {
     | val str = """(\d+)""".r findAllIn genre(1) mkString
     | val date = if(str.length == 4) str.toInt else 0
     | date >= 1985 && date <= 1995 && genre(2).contains("Horror")
     | })
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
horrorMovies: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] = MapPartitionsRDD[7] at filter at <console>:33
```

rest of the codes are same as above.

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: As we execute this line                                                                      
   scala> val horrorMovies = tags.filter(genre => {
     | val date = genre(1).substring(genre(1).lastIndexOf("(")+1, genre(1).lastIndexOf(")")).toInt
     | date >= 1985 && date <= 1995 && genre(2).contains("Horror")
     | }).take(5)                                                                                             
  It throws an error saying, java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

Comment: are there lines in your data without year? I mean without `(1995)` format?

Comment: I have not analysed the entire dataset though but I suppose it's the problem with dataset itself. When I am extracting some of the records to a text file & then applying the same logic, it works. So probable all the records are not similar. Thanks.

Comment: you can go with regex too :) is your problem solved ?

Comment: The logic is correct and working on a small set of data. I also tried using "indexOf" instead of "lastIndexOf" as the data is not consistent and we need the first opening parenthesis. lastIndexOf muft be giving the last opening parenthesis which must have generated the error. Could you please explain how can I proceed with regexs in the shell for the same. :)

Comment: I have updated :) if the answer is helpful please do upvote and accept as an answer :)